# Excel file validation and retrieving data from excel not working in yii2

Tags: validation, file-upload, yii2

My form is like this:
[image]

I have two buttons in my form.one is 'export' button and another is 'create' button.While saving the form i have to upload excel file.This excel file contains single row with 5 columns .On click  of export button i have to get all the values from excel and set those values in my form .Lastly on click of create button I have to save those values in database.
Here my problem is i am not being able to validate excel file and get values from excel to set data in my form.

My form code is:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'memform',
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal',['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],],
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "{label}\n<div class=\"col-lg-6\">{input}</div>\n<div class=\"col-lg-12\">{error}</div>",
        'labelOptions' => ['class' => 'col-lg-6 control-label'],

    ],
    ]); ?>


    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(); ?>

     <?= Html::a('export', ['import-excel','model' => $model], ['class' => 'btn btn-success','style' => 'float:left;width: 200px; border-radius: 5px;']) ?>

<h3 class="box-title">General Info:</h3> </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'regd_dt')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">

        <?= $form->field($model, 'estd_type')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(CodeValue::getEstdType(),'cv_id','cv_lbl'),
            ['prompt'=>'Select est Type']
         )
        ?>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-4">

        <?= $form->field($model, 'org_type')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(CodeValue::getOrgType(),'cv_id','cv_lbl'),
            ['prompt'=>'Select Org Type']
         )
        ?>
    </div>


    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

My controller is:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new GeneralInfo();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        return $this->redirect(['index', 'id' => $model->sfcl_id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}


public function actionImportExcel(){
    $model = new GeneralInfo();
    $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        $file = $model->file->tempName;
    if (isset(model->file)) {

        try{

            $inputFileType=\PHPExcel_IOFactory::Identify($file);
            $objReader=\PHPExcel_IOFactory::CreateReader($inputFileType);
            $objPHPExcel=$objReader->load($file);

        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            die('Error');
        }

        $sheet=$objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
        $highestRow=$sheet->getHighestRow();
        $highestColumn=$sheet->getHighestColumn();  
        for($row=1;$row<=$highestRow;$row++){
            $rowData=$sheet->rangeToArray('A'.$row.':'.$highestColumn.$row,Null,False);

            if($row==1){
                continue;
            }
            $sfcl=new GeneralInfo();
            $sfcl->name=$rowData[0][0];
            echo $sfcl->name;die;
        }
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('_form', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
}
```

and my model is like this:

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [

         ['file', 'required'],
         ['name','estd_dt', 'regd_dt', 'type', 'org_type'], 'required'],
         [['type', 'org_type', 'crtd_by', 'updt_by', 'updt_cnt'], 'integer'],
        [['name','estd_dt', 'regd_dt'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
        [['file'], 'file',  'extensions' => 'xls, xlsx', 'maxSize'=>1024*1024*20],
    ];
}
```

Comment: What action form sends data to?

Comment: actioncreate() is called on click of create button and on click of export button  actionImportExcel() is called

Comment: You are not calling validation there.

Comment: i used model->validate() it was not working

Comment: Where have you put it?

Comment: It should be after UploadedFile instance is created.

Comment: i had tried as you have said.but its not working still i am getting "Select File cannot be blank." and the file name gets refreshed on click of export button

Comment: Check content of $_FILES in the action. Maybe you are not sending the file properly.

Comment: can you give me code for doing that?

Comment: Seriously? `var_dump($_FILES);die;` is enough.

Comment: array(0) { }  on doing so

Comment: Oh, I've just noticed. You are using link to send this file instead of submit button. This will not work.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Use proper form submit button or try to send the file using AJAX.